# Loading a .js file conditionally. How?

Tags: javascript, head.js

First demo is a .js file which is loaded with:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zooming/1.4.2/zooming.js"></script>`
https://codepen.io/zuhocuyixu/pen/oqpdWz

 The .js adds a nice zooming feature to the image.

Second demo is trying to load the same .js file with head.js. It does not work.
https://codepen.io/zuhocuyixu/pen/XEVEwG

Any advice on why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking through [the zooming.js docs](https://desmonding.me/zooming/docs/#/guide)

You can initialize the zooming on images like this yourself:

```
head.ready(document, function() {
    head.load('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zooming/1.4.2/zooming.js', function() {
         var zooming = new Zooming();
         zooming.listen('.my-img');
    });
});
```

and change your html to this:

```
<img 
    class="my-img"
    style='max-width: 100%;'
    draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;"
    src="https://image.ibb.co/bxRTKn/trees_crop.jpg"
    data-original="https://preview.ibb.co/eRYm5S/trees.jpg"
    alt="test"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked a treat! I am quite new to web development and some things are a little difficult to understand. Here is a link to the final result. The code would only load the zooming feature on larger screens: _https://codepen.io/zuhocuyixu/pen/wmmyOZ_

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your dev tools, you will find `zooming` is actually loading.

Your problem is zooming is loaded after your document html has been loaded, so you will need to tell zooming to re-parse,.

I don't personally use Zooming, but try ->

```
head.load('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zooming/1.4.2/zooming.js', function () {
  new Zooming();
});
```